# Can't get input from radio buttons in PHP

Tags: php, html

My HTML code is as follows:

```
<form action="installs.php" method="get">
<input type="radio" name="interval" value="weekly">Weekly<br>
<input type="radio" name="interval" value="monthly" checked>Monthly<br>
</form>
```

And my PHP is simply

```
$temp = $_GET["interval"];
```

I already have another form of buttons and a select that I am successfully retrieving input from, what am I doing wrong here?

To answer some questions, installs.php is the name of the single file that I am writing this in. There are no other elements called 'interval'.

EDIT:
When I attempted to remove all other code in order to post it here, the call stack disappeared. It seems as though the issue may be elsewhere? I will update when I find the problem.

EDIT 2: 
I was mistaken about the earlier problem, I have successfully pared down the code with the problem still persisting. Now the entirety of installs.php is as such:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="installs.php" method="get">
    <input type="radio" name="interval" value="weekly">Weekly<br>
    <input type="radio" name="interval" value="monthly" checked>Monthly<br>
</form> 
</body>
</html>
<?php
 $temp = $_GET["interval"];
?>
```

Comment: if submitting a form the better method is to use `POST` and also ensure your `<form>` includes the `enctype='multipart/form-data'` parameter

Comment: on your php page write: `print_r($_REQUEST);` and you will view what is being given to the PHP by the form. From that you can establish where any issues lie

Comment: I couldn't find any mistake in your code. Is there any extra code block?

Comment: What do you get in `$temp`? Empty? Garbage?

Comment: @Martin will changing it to POST actually affect receiving the data? And the request merely says the same thing, that the index 'interval' is undefined.

Comment: I get a warning "undefined index 'interval'"

Comment: Just in case: you said you have another form, are you trying to submit 2 forms? If you want to submit all the data at the same time you'll have to wrap all of the input around one `form` tag.

Comment: No, I want to keep these forms separate. All I want is to read the current value of the radio button group if an event is triggered, but even if I try to read the value at the top level of the php I am unable to.

Comment: each form will only submit the data associated with that form, no other data. And changing to POST simply means that you'd need to update `$_GET['stuff']` to `$_POST['stuff']`

Comment: could you perhaps edit your question and show some more of your page code, as the code currently on display shows no issues and should work

Comment: Interesting, I remember seeing 'this' question before, today!!

Comment: @FirstOne the original post stated OP has asked this question earlier, I removed that text as superfluous to the question here. View my edit history on this question. I did view the OP profile but saw no other question like this so it was deleted maybe...

Comment: I deleted the earlier post because I did not know if duplicate posts would be allowed. I took into account everyone's comments on the previous post and answered the questions you had responded with when I made this post. Thank you for taking the time to post, sorry I couldn't respond earlier.

Comment: Did you try the answer that recommends to use `if ( isset . . .` ? Did it work? Not?

Comment: I already set one of the radio buttons as checked, would isset make a difference here?

Comment: Yes, the checked radio button will be submitted, so it will exist as `$_GET`, if no radio button is checked nothing would be submitted, so $_GET will not exist.

Comment: isset is always returning false.

Comment: debugging: 1) add a hidden field to your form with  a value of 'Hello' in it.  2) var_dump($_POST) early in your script? You should always see that hidden field when the form is sent. You will see one of the radio fields as well? I **always** have a hidden field on my form - as do most of you. see CSRF. imo, Every html form should have one.

Comment: Even with the hidden field, var_dump returns an empty array.

Comment: Add a submit button to your form. I am just looking at the code in your question.

Comment: When I submit using a submit button, var_dump returns both the hidden and submit fields but not the radio buttons.

Comment: Now, select one of the radio buttons - it will be in the input - sorry - var_dump($_GET) not post. I forget that anyone uses $_GET for forms. Hmm, please always use 'method=post' in forms. No-one needs to see a URL with a copy amd paste of a small email message in the URL? Also, it is limited to about 8K. Whatever, the only mistake you made in the code was to not have a 'submit' button in your form.

Comment: It worked! Sorry, forgot I had the automatic check for the radio button on. I  had hoped I would not need a submit button to passively get data from the radio buttons, but I suppose I will just have to implement it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Check if variable exists :

```
<form action="installs.php" method="get">
<input type="radio" name="interval" value="weekly">Weekly<br>
<input type="radio" name="interval" value="monthly" checked>Monthly<br>
</form> 

<?php
if ( isset( $_GET["interval"] ) )   // <====================
   $temp = $_GET["interval"];
?>
```

Comment: fifth comment down on the question, OP states that the result of `print_r($_REQUEST)`  (which is the same as your GET) is undefined index.

Comment: different methods, same outcome. Undefined index.

Comment: @Martin, in my computer it seems to work, no more "undefined index" error message. If I remove `isset` then I get the "undefined index" again. So, `isset` is the solution.

Comment: I think the issue is that the value *should* be defined, so just hiding the error message with an IF statement does not solve the issue itself. That's my interpretation of the question.

Comment: @Martin, if the variable is not defined means the form has not been submitted. The variable exists after the form is submitted. The `if` is not "hiding" any error, the if detects the before and the after the form is submitted.

Comment: it means *that form element* has not been submitted. I think there is an issue that OP is submitting a second form or there's otherwise something else on their code that we can't (yet) see.

Answer (score 1):

index.php

```
<html>
    <form action="installs.php" method="get">
        <input type="radio" name="interval" value="weekly">Weekly<br>
        <input type="radio" name="interval" value="monthly" checked>Monthly<br>
        <input type="submit" name="SEND"> <!-- ADD THIS LINE -->
    </form>
</html>
```

installs.php:

```
<?php
    $temp = $_GET["interval"];
    echo $temp;
?>
```

This work fine in my webserver

Answer (score 0):

try $_REQUEST['interval']; instead

Comment: I end up with the same warning of an undefined index.

Comment: Please don't use $_REQUEST. By default it gets clobbered by cookies. And if you use parameters in the URL (get) and form (post) it can be confusing which you actually received.